# How to add /kg or /each after price in WooCommerce when selling based on weight and unit

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I don't want to do complicated price calculations, I just want to display **/kg** when I'm selling the product by weight or **/each** when I'm selling the product by the unit to be shown after product price in the same shop.
for example:

1. if the product is a shirt, I would like the price to show like $9.99/each.
2. if the product is Apples, I would like the price to show like $2.99/kg.

Is there a simple way to achieve this?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the following code to add a suffix after the price

It is checked by product category, because in a certain way you have to determine what the product belongs to

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/has_term/

Unless you want to determine in another way how to check where the product belongs to?

```php
function add_price_suffix( $html, $product, $price, $qty ) {
    // Category - shirt
    if ( has_term( 'shirt', 'product_cat' ) ) {
        $html .= '/each.';
    } elseif ( has_term( 'apples', 'product_cat' ) ) {
        $html .= '/kg.';        
    } else {
        $html .= '/.';          
    }

    return $html;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_price_suffix', 'add_price_suffix', 10, 4 );
```

Comment: Thank you for your great answer, sometimes I need to sell apples by weight and by the unit as well depends on the brand. Some apples come in a bag so it should be sold by the unit.